# Saving string data in Dynamodb with lamda not working

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am simple creating a post api in which sending data to DynamoDb which i working with hardcoded data but dont know why when i am trying to add the event values its not working.

My lambda function

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-2', apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const params = {
        Item: {
            "QuestionID": {
                S: context.awsRequestId
            },
            "Would": {
                S: event.would
            },
            "Rather": {
                S: event.rather
            },
            "wouldClick": {
                N: event.wouldClick
            },
            "ratherClick": {
                N: event.ratherClick
            }
        },
        TableName: "Would-You-Rather"
    };
    dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);

            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```

This is my model use in post method

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "WouldYouRatherModel",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "would": {"type": "string"},
    "rather": {"type": "string"},
    "wouldClick": {"type": "integer"},
    "ratherClick": {"type": "integer"}
  },
  "required": ["would", "rather", "wouldClick", "ratherClick"]
}
```

My integration request mapping

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "would" : "$inputRoot.would",
    "rather" : "$inputRoot.rather",
    "wouldClick" : "$inputRoot.wouldClick",
    "ratherClick" : "$inputRoot.ratherClick"
}
```

If i hardcoded the values in lamda function and test in lamda its saving the values in database this is how i am hardcoding values

```
   "QuestionID": {
        S: context.awsRequestId
    },
    "Would": {
        S: "helllo"
    },
    "Rather": {
        S: "bye"
    },
    "wouldClick": {
        N: 1
    },
    "ratherClick": {
        N: 2
    }
```

But problem is when I add the event values in lambda function and try to test the post API from resources it's showing this error

```
"errorMessage": "There were 2 validation errors:\n* InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Item['wouldClick'].N to be a string\n* InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Item['ratherClick'].N to be a string"
```

I think the issue is in I am passing the string value in the wrong way? because if there is something wrong in lamda or module then the hardcoded values will also not save in DynamoDB its causing error when I send the values.

Comment: add a console to check typeof event.ratherClick and event.wouldClick and check you are getting number or string if you getting string then parse that to integer

Answer (score 0):

Even though `wouldClick` and `ratherClick` are Number types (N), they need to be passed to DynamoDB as strings. That is what the error message is telling you.

[The documentation on DynamoDB attribute values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) says:

> Numbers are sent across the network to DynamoDB as strings, to maximize compatibility across languages and libraries. However, DynamoDB treats them as number type attributes for mathematical operations.

The Number variables should be formatted as follows:

```
"wouldClick": { "N": "1" },
"ratherClick": { "N": "2" }
```